# Collision Detection With a Gapped Sprite LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection, sprite

I need an object to be able to go through a gap in a sprite but collide with any part of it. The sprite is similar to that below:

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\.............///////////////////////////////

The white in the image between the two branches (the dots) is transparent, not white.

I've seen countless tutorials where a rectangle is drawn around the sprite but the problem is that it won't work in this case, as you can probably see. Using area overlap could be a possibility, but I have no idea how to find the area of the sprite, if I could, I could use something like this, as I've seen on another post:

```
public static boolean testIntersection(Shape shape, Branches branches){
       Area shapearea = new Area(shape);
       areaA.intersect(new Area(branches));
       return !areaA.isEmpty();
}
```

Spawning them separately isn't an option as the x must be random, but the distance apart must remain the same.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a class for this special Sprite? Or is it just a sprite you draw? IF you use a class you could save two collidable Areas there (they could be 2 Rectangles) and in collision detection you just check for collision with this 2 Areas.

Comment: It was originally a class, but then I made it draw. I can easily change it back, thanks for the idea.

Comment: No problem. Tell me if it works :)